# What could cause ti.cloud to stop display Android Push Notifications (GCM) in status bar

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules, appcelerator-arrow

I previously setup an Appcelerator Titanium project with push notifications (as per my Stack Overflow question [How to configure Android Push Notifications (GCM) in Appcelerator Titanium Dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851380/how-to-configure-android-push-notifications-gcm-in-appcelerator-titanium-dashb)) and for some months my Android app has been receiving the appropriate push notification from GCM, but I'm now receiving reports that this no longer works from end-users.

The flow usually goes like this...

- Android app sends android push token to my Java server
- Java server persists the Android push token
- Java server sets up Amazon Web Service SNS endpoint for GCM and stores this endpoint for later use.

(some time passes)

- Java server invokes Amazon Web Service SNS endpoint with a GCM payload
- Amazon SNS passes message to Google GCM
- GCM passes message to ti.cloud / ti.cloudpush
- Phone displays push notification

The app does receive the push notification and I display an application dialog to show the contents of the message, but NO system-tray push notification is displayed, whereas I thought it was doing this in the past.  No system sound is played either.

I can see that *if* the app is not running, then when the push notification is received the app is launched, but if the display isn't on (or locked) then the message will not be discovered for some time.  I really need the native/system push notification to be in the tray.

Does anyone know why system / status notifications are not displayed? Should it be when using the ti.cloud / ti.cloudpush for Android?

Thanks
Rob.

Comment: Are you using SDK 6.0.0?

Comment: Hi @GerbenHofman, 

I'm building using Titanium 5.5.0.GA, the device is running Android 6.  I don't see the 'Android' SDK version if that's what you're referring to?